# Should we have pixel-art tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've created it, but @RayMairlot expressed doubt that there is enough questions to warrant it.

I think it's needed because it is a unique art style that requires specific settings and unique compositing setups as it's partially opposite to goals of approximately half of renderings, realism, and is different from cartoon renders too. I've started working on pixel art in Blender to help filling a [new tileset for Cataclysm DDA](https://github.com/I-am-Erk/CDDA-Tilesets) game and there is at least two other artists in the chat of only that small project who were excited to learn that Blender is partially feasible for pixel art because they can work in Blender too, not counting likes on the forum.

I've also published my setup at https://github.com/int-ua/blender-pixelart if you would like to learn more and maybe help.

#### Edit

List of questions that I think are relevant:

[Any workflow recommendation for 2.5-D pixel art style?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/155469/1958)

[Pixelate the viewport camera in Eevee for previewing live pixel art / low-resolution render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/188023/1958)

[Is there a way to force pixellate the viewport render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164678/1958)

[How to not distort pixels?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/55902/1958)

[Pixelart style render in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17846/1958)

[Rendering a pixelated image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39859/1958)

[Freestyle without anti aliasing for pixel art (2.8)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/148955/1958)

[How do I generate pixel-art friendly UV maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/119971/1958)

[Pixelate Node: Scaling Produces Missing Pixels On Border](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/178758/1958)

[How can I render pixel art images with no AA and transparent background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/119728/1958)

[How to render small object, as pixel art, without losing any of the pixels (Cycles render)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/135483/1958)

[Creating 3D pixel modeling?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18318/1958)

[How to disable anti-aliasing in the background images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/77933/1958)

[How to generate a fake hand painted texture (Blizzard like), Borderlands effect or Pixel Art effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/90152/1958)

[How can I keep low resolution textures pixelated?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2586/1958)

[How to render a model with pixel art/sprite textures and have it not be blurry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/47943/1958) (duplicate of the previous one)

[Can't crop image's size in Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/150834/1958)

... I'm tired of this, maybe I'll continue the list later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a moderator, but I try to keep on top of new tag creation to try and keep the number of tags ordered and manageable.

I am generally of the opinion that it's only worth creating a tag when there are a 'good enough' number of questions about the topic that may need the new tag. For example, if there was only 1 question that could benefit from a new tag, I would say that the tag is not necessary. So how many questions *does* it take before a tag might be useful? 15? 20? This is what I don't know. If there were 20 I would certainly start to think that a tag could be useful.

Regarding the [pixel-art](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixel-art) tag, while I am not wholly against it, I searched for "pixel art" and "pixelart" and it seems there's around 10 questions on the site about pixel art. I am unsure whether this is a big enough amount of questions to warrant the new tag.

However, it may be that I need to change my way of thinking about tags. The Stackoverflow Meta question, '[When is it appropriate to create a new?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)' tag says:

> If you have enough reputation to create the tag, and if you think
> there is a clear need for a tag, go ahead and create it yourself.
> Uncommon topics are perfectly valid for a tag, as long as they're
> still clearly defined.

But the comments on that question seem to throw into doubt what "clear need" actually means.

The [help centre](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) says:

> **When should I create new tags?**
>
> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always
> favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a
> strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else
> has asked about before on this site.

After reading these pages, I am inclined to say the new tag *should* exist and I shouldn't be basing it on numbers.

I am interested to hear what other people say. If others are fine with tags being created for a small number of questions (as long as the new tag is for a distinct topic, which pixel art is), then maybe I should be too.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try gathering the questions I consider relevant in a separate answer to discuss them briefly maybe.

Comment: @int_ua If you're going to add them I would maybe add them to your question.

Answer (score 4):

There are currently 44 [questions containing the phrase "pixel art"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20pixel%20art), 24 of which [have accepted answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20hasaccepted%3Ayes%20pixel%20art), though 10 [have no answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20answers%3A0%20pixel%20art). I think this indicates enough interest to justify the tag. We [currently have 72 tags which have fewer than 44 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/edit/1269007). Some of those tags may be of questionable value admittedly, but certainly not all (e.g. [blend-modes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-modes)).

Welcome [pixel-art](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixel-art)!

Comment: There is a difference between search results that match pixel art and questions that are *about* pixel art, but just mention it in passing.

Comment: For example [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181092/2-8-streched-texture) seems like a regular texturing question.

Comment: There does seem to be a surprising amount of questions about it, by the numbers alone it would indeed seem to warrant the tag existence. My questions is mostly about its actual usefulness, tagging a question "pixel-art" tells us very little about its content. Is it about texture filtering, is it about rendering, compositing, antialiasing? It can encompass wildly different things not necessarily related

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos As it is quite distinct in terms of settings/setup, people who work on pixel art and will supposedly be subscribed to the tag either will benefit from discovering a new challenge or method to solve it or will already know the answer irrespectively of the actual topic, just because the result that is required is relevant to what they do. That's an approximate description of how I see it.

Comment: Well I don't often work with pixel art, but if you say so I won't disagree. I have my reservations, but I don't have strong feelings about it. Anyway I have accepted all your edits to include the tag in questions so far, so those should be easier to find for all interested in the future.